# Adding more data to a structure

Tags: c

I have created a function that would add books to a structure but when I try to add more books, the previous book is deleted. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

```
void addBooks(void)
{
    char chChoice;
    int cnt = 0;

    printf("\n\t\t~~ADD NEW BOOK\n");

    printf("Enter the isbn: ");
    scanf("%d", &b[cnt].nid);
    printf("Enter books title: ");
    scanf("%s", b[cnt].chTitle);

    printf("The record was saved successfully!");

    printf("Save more books? (Y / N) ");
    scanf("%s", &chChoice);
    if (chChoice == 'y')
    {
        addBooks();
        cnt = cnt + 1;
    }
    else
        mainMenu();
}
```

Comment: What is `b`? Could you create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Please provide more information about the struct and how the b[] array(?) is declared/defined.  You might consider passing a pointer to the current b[cnt] element of the array, and return a status from addBooks() to indicate =1 you got a book, or =0 you didn't get a book.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &chChoice);` : `"%s"` --> `" %c"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void addBooks(int cnt) //parameter
{
    char chChoice;
   // int cnt = 0;

    printf("\n\t\t~~ADD NEW BOOK\n");

    printf("Enter the isbn: ");
    scanf("%d", &b[cnt].nid);
    printf("Enter books title: ");
    scanf("%s", b[cnt].chTitle);

    printf("The record was saved successfully!");

    printf("Save more books? (Y / N) ");
    scanf(" %c", &chChoice);
    if (chChoice == 'y')
    {
        addBooks(cnt+1);
    }
    else
        mainMenu();
}
```

You need `cnt` as a parameter else as `cnt` is local,you reset the value to 0 itself. You could also declare `cnt` as `static` and if you do so,don't forget to increment `cnt` before calling your function. Also,use `%c` for a character and not `%s`.

Answer (score 1):

Each time addBooks() is called the value of cnt is reset to zero by the fourth line in your code.  Replace that line with:

```
static int cnt = 0;
```

This will cause the value to be set to zero only on the first call of addBooks().

In addition you must increment the value of cnt before you recursively call addBooks() like so:

```
if (chChoice == 'y')
{
    cnt = cnt + 1;
    addBooks();
}
```

Comment: I've deleted my answer since it was incomplete. Why don't you update your answer to have the full solution.